# Some HTML/CSS effect that I want to learn more, but can't describe

Tags: html, css

I was just browsing this BBC travel page [*50 Reasons 
to #LoveTheWorld*](http://www.bbc.com/travel/bespoke/story/20150309-50-reasons-to-love-the-world/index.html) and realized that on bigger pictures, the page overlaps and as we scroll, there is this cool effect (hadn't seen in other websites I visit). I wanted to learn more about it, but I don't even know what to search for.

As we scroll, on big pictures, the page still scrolls and the picture is exposed, it's kind of hard to explain. Could someone tell me what are those kind of effect called, may be a tutorial if one is available, or just the name would be helpful enough.

Comment: I believe what you want is called parallax scrolling.  You can find a lot of good libraries for it with google.

Comment: That 'this' is the link.  @soong That looks like it. Thanks.

Comment: I answered a similar question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27233147/how-can-i-create-overlapping-images-that-reveal-themselves-as-you-scroll/27234722#27234722

Answer (score 3):

The page you linked uses only `background-attachment: fixed;`.

*It actually uses absolutely positioned `img` elements which are `translated` on `scrolling` to 'stay fixed', but visual results are pretty much the same as when background is `fixed` (and it's size set to `cover`). This approach is much simpler for checking out the basics of this technique.*

Although very simple, it can provide interesting effects when used on a large (background) images, or multiple revealing rows of images.

Here's a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a8pr7y4z/1/). That's the basic concept.

[Refference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp)

Answer (score 1):

This is called `Parallax`

You can setup a basic Parallax markup as stated by Keith Clark in his Pure CSS parallax  article.

```
<div class="parallax">
  <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Then styling it like so:

```
.parallax {
  perspective: 1px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.parallax__layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.parallax__layer--base {
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
.parallax__layer--back {
  transform: translateZ(-1px);
}
```

Look at the demo [Here](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/demo3/).

The full article which goes into good detail is [Here](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/).

Comment: The effect on the page the question linked to isn't parallax, no perspective is involved.