# Smooth mouse scroll upward using Jquery and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am try to make a smooth scroll upward and downward but having issue with the follow up image. t

```
  $(window).scroll(function(event) {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll < 400) {
      $('#two').css('position', 'fixed');
      $('#three').css('position', 'fixed');
    }    

    if (scroll > 400 && scroll < 900) {
      $('#two').css('position', 'absolute');
      $('#three').css('position', 'fixed');
    }  


  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/KingJef/6q47vmhn/32/

Answer (score 0):

I have found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27233147/how-can-i-create-overlapping-images-that-reveal-themselves-as-you-scroll) with a similar dynamics, following the proposal of the author of the question it is possible to do the same in your question:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).scrollTop(1);

  var img1 = $('#one');
  var posimg1 = img1.position().top;
  var img2 = $('#two');
  var posimg2 = img2.position().top;
  var img3 = $('#three');
  var posimg3 = img3.position().top;
    
  $(window).scroll(function(event) {

    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    
    if (scroll <= posimg1) {
      img1.addClass('latched');
    } else {
      img1.removeClass('latched');
    }
    if (scroll <= posimg2) {
      img2.addClass('latched');
    } else {
      img2.removeClass('latched');
    }
    if (scroll <= posimg3) {
      img3.addClass('latched');
    }

  });
});
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/pr0mming/ybar8onj/14/

Apparently the error is to preserve the `absolute` images with css, instead of this they are left in `fixed` and the property would be eliminated once the scroll is exceeded (visibility level) but otherwise the images should be kept in `fixed`.

But there is a shorter solution with the same algorithm, of course, it is simply to add this *magic css* and remove it as the case may be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function(event) {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll < 500) {
      $('#two').css('position', 'fixed');
      $('#three').css('position', 'fixed');
    }

    if (scroll > 500 && scroll < 1600) {
      $('#two').removeAttr( 'style' );
      $('#three').css({ position: 'fixed', top: 0, width: 'auto' });
    }
    else {
      $('#two').css({ position: 'fixed', top: 0, width: 'auto' });
      $('#three').css({ position: 'fixed', top: 0, width: 'auto' });
    }

  });
});
```